# SSIS Send Mail task script with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sendmail

I am having a challenge with this send mail script in visual studio 2010.

Here is the script:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
namespace ST_dd466aa1cac943eb887bc0d48f753e68
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        public void Main()
        {
            string sSubject = "Test Subject";
            string sBody = "Test Message";
            int iPriority = 2;

            if (SendMail(sSubject, sBody, iPriority))
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                //Fails the Task
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }

        public bool SendMail(string sSubject, string sMessage, int iPriority)
        {
            try
            {
                string sEmailServer = Dts.Variables["sEmailServer"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailPort = Dts.Variables["sEmailPort"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailUser = Dts.Variables["sEmailUser"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailPassword = Dts.Variables["sEmailPassword"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailSendTo = Dts.Variables["sEmailSendTo"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailSendCC = Dts.Variables["sEmailSendCC"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailSendFrom = Dts.Variables["sEmailSendFrom"].Value.ToString();
                string sEmailSendFromName = Dts.Variables["sEmailSendFromName"].Value.ToString();

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailSendFrom, sEmailSendFromName);

                //You can have multiple emails separated by ;
                string[] sEmailTo = Regex.Split(sEmailSendTo, ";");
                string[] sEmailCC = Regex.Split(sEmailSendCC, ";");
                int sEmailServerSMTP = int.Parse(sEmailPort);

                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.Host = sEmailServer;
                smtpClient.Port = sEmailServerSMTP;

                System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
                   new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailUser, sEmailPassword);
                smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

                message.From = fromAddress;

                if (sEmailTo != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sEmailTo.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (sEmailTo[i] != null && sEmailTo[i] != "")
                        {
                            message.To.Add(sEmailTo[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (sEmailCC != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sEmailCC.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (sEmailCC[i] != null && sEmailCC[i] != "")
                        {
                            message.To.Add(sEmailCC[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                switch (iPriority)
                {
                    case 1:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
                        break;
                    default:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                        break;
                }

                //You can enable this for Attachments.  
                //SingleFile is a string variable for the file path.
                //foreach (string SingleFile in myFiles)
                //{
                //    Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(SingleFile);
                //    message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
                //}


                message.Subject = sSubject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = sMessage;

                smtpClient.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{

            //    return false;
            //}

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "ST_dd466aa1cac943eb887bc0d48f753e68", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                return false;
            }
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

and here is the error I get:

> SSIS package "C:\Users\xxx\xxxx\visual studio 2010\projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxx.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0xFFFFFFFF at Script Task, ST_dd466aa1cac943eb887bc0d48f753e68: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>      at ST_dd466aa1cac943eb887bc0d48f753e68.ScriptMain.SendMail(String sSubject, String sMessage, Int32 iPriority)
>   Error: 0x6 at Script Task: The script returned a failure result.
>   Task failed: Script Task

SSIS package "C:\Users\xxx\xxxx\visual studio 2010\projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxx.dtsx" finished: Success.

Secondly, I would like to have an attachment as a variable as well.

Between, I am using godaddy email, windows server 2012R2 and visual studio 2010.

Comment: Your getting to the Send Mail, it is timing out so the server may not have access or there is a delay in response from GoDaddy server causing the timeout

Comment: Thanks for this Brad but I have granted access through the administrative tools of the server - is there another access I need to grant or what access do I need to grant? Cheers

Comment: Wasnt clear on that sorry, access meaning can the computer reach GoDaddy servers (due to firewalls, restrictions on the server, other stuff like that).

Does it run locally on your machine?

Comment: here is what the firewall settings on the server are: Inbound and Outbound connections are all allowed in the domain, private and public profile. I will try and run it on my mac to see if it runs. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

For your attachments you can do this where EmailAttachmentPaths is a string with the paths comma delimited

```
// this is to add multipel attachments ","
            string[] ToMuliPaths = EmailAttachmentPaths.Split(',');
            foreach (string ToPathId in ToMuliPaths)
            {
                // only add email if not blank
                if (ToPathId.Trim() != "")
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ToPathId));
            }// end for loop
```